# Checking top values for dataframe columns in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataset that looks like:

```
Shop              Date           Hour Ending         Hours Operating        Produced   
Cornerstop        01-01-2010          0                     1                   9
Cornerstop        01-01-2010          1                     1                   11
Cornerstop        01-01-2010          2                     1                   10
. 
.

Cornerstop        01-01-2010          23                    1                   0
Leaf Grove        01-01-2010          0                     1                   7
Leaf Grove        01-01-2010          1                     1                   4
Leaf Grove        01-01-2010          2                     1                   2
```

I want to find out which shops are the top 20 shops by how much they've produced. I've used `data.describe()` to check the top percentiles but this doesn't help me because if I threshold on the top percentile of 'Produced' some days are lost in the data.

This is a newbie question but how can I easily pick and target these top shops based on this criteria? Perhaps use the percentile just to create a range of the top shops and just cut those out in the dataset? Feels like there's a much better way to do this.

Comment: Is it the sum of the total production per shop? Or just the top 20 rows with the highest value of produced? In that case, can the same shop appear more than once?

Comment: Good question which leads me to a probably easy answer. I want the top 20 based off the sum of the production. I can just sum on the dates by produced sum. What operation could I use to quickly show me the top values for each date after that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sort_values()` and `head()`:

```
df.sort_values('Produced', ascending=False).head(20)
```

If you want to sum the production values for each shop and then sort, you can do:

```
df.groupby('Shop').agg({'Produced': 'sum'}).sort_values('Produced', ascending=False).head(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the following to sort the column and then take the top 20?

```
df= df.sort_values(['Produced'], ascending=[False])
df.head(20)
```

Comment: I think we must both have posted answers at the same time!

Comment: This only gives me the top 20 values of any given Shop (so it spits out the top 20 Produced values for one Shop in the list).

Comment: Apologies. I’ve now edited my answer. It should be better now

Answer (score 0):

Use `.nlargest`

```
df.groupby('Shop').Produced.sum().nlargest(20)
```

Add `.index.tolist()` if you just need a list of Shops.

Comment: The name of the column doesn't actually work here as .Produced.sum().

Comment: I don't understand. I'm accessing your column named `'Produced'` and then calculating the sum of those values within each `'Shop'`. This should work if your `DataFrame` has the columns in your example.

Comment: I actually have the name as 'Produced Today (lb)' for the column. Introducing spaces into the name might be the reason.

Comment: Yes, if you have spaces you cannot use the `.` notation so it needs to be `df.groupby('Shop')['Produced Today (lb)'].sum().nlargest(20)`